# How to verify $\frac{\sin x\pm\sin y}{\cos x+\cos y}=\tan\frac{x\pm y}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

Can anyone help me verify the following identity?
$$
\frac{\sin x\pm\sin y}{\cos x+\cos y}=\tan\frac{x\pm y}{2}
$$
I could really use some guidance.

Comment: Usually it is a shorthand for two separate equations, in the above case one equation is with both $\pm$s replaced by $+$ and the other has $\pm$ replaced by $-$.

Comment: @copper.hat , thanks for your response, but can you (according to this info) help me verify the above identities ?

Comment: @copper.hat Look at how your comment appears--it looks like a really trippy version of -.- ... see it?

Comment: @AhmedMostafa, See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sin x+\sin y=2\sin\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)$$
$$\sin x -\sin y=2\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)$$
$$\cos x+\cos y=2\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)$$
$$\frac{\sin x+\sin y}{\cos x+\cos y}=\frac{2\sin(\frac{x+y}{2})\cos(\frac{x-y}{2})}{2\cos(\frac{x+y}{2})\cos(\frac{x-y}{2})}=\frac{\sin(\frac{x+y}{2})}{\cos(\frac{x+y}{2})}=\tan\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)$$
and the same method for the other!

Comment: Thanks a lot bro (Y) much appreciated :)

Comment: No problem, I hope its clear!